# Why isn't my chat post working on my Tumblr theme?

Tags: html, tumblr

This is my Tumblr theme.

http://lt-2014.tumblr.com/

I made a chat post and nothing is showing up and here is the code I have.

```
{block:Chat} 
<div class="chat">
{block:Title}<h1 class="title">{Title}</h1>{/block:Title}
<ul>
{block:Lines}<li class="{Alt}"><p>{block:Label}<strong>{Label}</strong>{/block:Label} {Line} </p></li>{/block:Lines}
</ul>
</div>
{/block:Chat}
```

Why isn't my chat post showing up despite this code I put? Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Again, please post *all* of your Tumblr theme's code somewhere. It's impossible to diagnose just from this. I assume there's a problem somewhere else in your theme.

Comment: Here's the code to my whole Tumblr theme. Not even the audio nor video posts show up.

http://pastebin.com/9m9y5WWa

Answer (score 2):

On line 75 of your theme file you have a closing `{/block:Posts}` which means none of the post tags written after that will work. Move `{/block:Posts}` to *after* your last post type.

Comment: Check out the answer to this question to learn how to accept answers on Stack Overflow ;)